# Using Firebug From Within a Firefox Extension's code

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

Does anyone know how I can use firebug from an overlay.js script in a Firefox extension? I'm on Snow Leopard (just in case it makes a difference).

I'm developing an extension but it's taking me forever because I have no visibility into my javascript objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what you really need is **ChromeBug**, created by the Firebug team.

ChromeBug is a Firebug version that can debug XUL elements, that is, a Firebug that can debug Firefox extensions.

See more about it here:
http://blog.getfirebug.com/2009/10/12/chromebug-1-5a4/

Answer (score 1):

Try using **[FireBug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/lite.html)**. It's a handy substitute for the real deal -- essentially it's a Javascript file you can package up on your site or custom extension.

Answer (score 1):

Install FirebugLite and use the following to log things to console:

```
Firebug.Console.log('things to log...');
```